# Connecting Facebook's API "taggable_friends" and "friends" Nodes

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I'm working on a webapp and we're integrating facebook (through facebook's [sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.3) and [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) so user's can have a simple profile created on login. I've gone through 'most' of version 2.3's documentation and learned about all the new permission changes and such (man I wish I'd been able to learn the sdk when v1.0 was primarily in use).

What I can't seem to find is whether or not the "taggable_friends" node encapsulates the "friends" nodes. In other words, if I have a menu of a user's taggable_friends, how can I update the database once a friend uses my webapp and accepts the permissions?

I've been looking for something that relates "taggable_friends" and "friends" but it appears name is the only persistent data. The taggable_friends node only shows an id (not the same id as the app id assigned to a user using the webapp, more of an access token id only facebook seems to decode), name (for obvious reasons not acceptable), and profile picture icon url. For the record, I did try finding a "friends" (someone already using the app/has accepted the permissions) profile picture icon url but alas could not. One workaround could be finding the profile pictures photo id of "friends" and sending it back to facebook to retrieve the profile picture icon photo id of that friend, and seeing if it matches the profile picture icon url from the "taggable_friends" list, however that would be a management nightmare and I don't even know if the photo id's would match up in the end.

If anyone has an experience in the v2.0 facebook api and working with taggable_friends vs friends node server side, I would love some help/feedback.

Please let me know if I can explain anything more thoroughly or supply more links.

tl;dr Does facebook's javascript sdk and graph api's nodes "taggable_friends" also list friends from the "friends" node? [Has to be version 2.0 and above]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  taggable_friends is available so your user can tag their friends in things.  Why would you need to marry that to a real friend object?

Comment: I'm trying to allow users to see a full list of their facebook friends and click on their friends that are already using the app. I envision "taggable_friends" to be greyed out and "friends" using the app to be clickable. A "friend" has something of a profile associated with them, however listing both "friends" and "taggable_friends" would lead to each person being duplicated when the start using the web app (cross checking through names fails if two+ friends have the same name...)